# Re-entering with B1/B2 visa

Tags: usa

Istayed in the States on a B2 visa (Malaysian passport) for 10 months (was granted 6 months by CBP but extension for 6-months was approved). I was on holiday and never worked. My boyfriend is American and I was traveling to America to be with him and the CBP is aware of that.

When I left the States 3 weeks ago returning to Australia, I applied for an E3 visa. I was offered a role in a Finance company in the States. Expecting to return to the states with my Australian passport with new visa attached but the visa issuing system is facing technical difficulties globally and I am waiting for them to send out my Australian passport. Because we don't know when the system will be up, I need to return to the States with my B2 visa on my Malaysian passport for 2.5 weeks for a meeting with my prospective employer and attend a very important event. I will depart the country in 2.5 weeks and will have an air ticket ready to show.

Will I have any problem?

Comment: As long as you are meeting a prospective employer, you should be fine. You definitely cannot work in the US during that time, but meeting a prospective employer is fine. People do this all the time for job interviews.

Comment: @ChromoZoneX isn't meeting a prospective employer a B1 purpose?  Nelly, is your visa B2 or B1/B2?

Comment: This is better for the expatriates.SE.  But being in the US on a B1/B2 visa isn't a problem.  But you won't be able to work.

Comment: Nelly: If your visa is B2 only, consider asking for your passport back so you can travel to the US on the visa waiver program.  US missions have been making people's passports available to them for situations like this, caused by the visa-issuing problems.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the prompt response! The only reason I don't want to get my Australian passport back is because I do not want to cause anymore delays in my E3 processing. My employer has been kind enough to wait this long.

Comment: I am on a B2 visa but my concern is renters get the country so quickly after such a long stay. Though my reasons are legit and I have an exit to Mexico for the final leg of my holiday before work commence and I'll probably be chained to a desk for a while!

Comment: Phoog: actually the visa on my passport states B1/B2. Does that mean I have both?

Comment: @phoog Yes, it is a B1 purpose. I legitimately thought they always issue B1/B2. I have never been issued just one of them. But yes, to be precise you need to have a B1 (business) visa.

Comment: Nelly: yes, of course.  In that case, you can use that visa to travel for a business meeting.  @ChromoZoneX I am a US citizen and my wife is on a G visa, so I have no experience with B visas.  I have read that it is possible to get a visa that is only B1 or B2, but I don't know whether it actually happens in practice.

Comment: @phoog I often briefly enter the US on transit or otherwise, and I have always gotten a B1 / B2 visa. But, I don't think there is any way to be certain. So, in this case, please make sure you don't get just a B2 visa.

Comment: Flagged for migration.

Comment: @chromozonex apparently the US issues single-purpose visas mostly in cases where its [reciprocity rules](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/Visa-Reciprocity-and-Civil-Documents-by-Country.html) for a given country provide for different conditions for the different types of visa. In some cases there might be a reciprocity fee for one type of visa but not the other, or the maximum validity of the different types might be different. It seems that combined visas are the most common because the vast majority of countries have the same conditions for both types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it most definitely will be a problem. While you may not be actually lying, the CBP officer may decide not to believe you and send you back where you came from because he'll suspect you're trying to start working before you have the valid visa to enter in the correct status.

Get in touch with the employer's immigration attorney before you do anything stupid. Once you're escorted back to the plane from the CBP immigration inspection, it will be much harder for you to get any US visa.